# How to Skip Non Existent keys using Python and MongoDB without KeyErrors

Tags: python, django, mongodb, dictionary

Am using MongoDB to store few event details from embedded devices and Django as web application wrapper around the data. device_events collection has records of type:

```
{"key1": value1,
 "key2": value2,
 "key3": value3, 
 "key4" : {
    "type" : "Point", 
    "coordinates" : [
        87.55092545050022, 
        25.037010399709558
    ]
}, 
 "key5": value5,
}
```

In the same collection, few records could be of another type:

```
  {"key9": value9,
     "keyx": valuex,
     "key3": value3, 
     "key4" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            87.55092545050022, 
            25.037010399709558
        ]
    }, 
     "key5": value5,
    }
```

When i query for all records in a collection, i would get list of above all dict's. I would like to use map-lambda to get only required  fields data.

Now the problem is, few fields exists for one record, for few they won't. I need to show the field in the report irrespective of existence and probably with null/zero if key not present.

My map function is:

```
data ={
        "data" : map(
            lambda m: {
                "id": m["key1"], "longitude": m["key4"]["coordinates"][0], "latitude": m["key4"]["coordinates"][1],"active_status" : m["keyx"]
            },
            all_devices
        )
    }
```

Which throws, KeyError: 'id'.

I need to use it for reports with large set of data, efficient solution with minimal overhead is needed. [I meant checking every dict in the list for every key isn't optimal solution in this case.]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your phrase "few fields exists for one record, for few they won't. I need to show the field in the report irrespective of existence and probably with null/zero if key not present."

Comment: Could you give a real example, I tried your code in a simplified way (which I understood) and got no problem/errors.

Comment: Hi,
key1 is present in first dict and it is not present in second dict. when i tried to map key1 for the second dict also, it throws KeyError.

Comment: If you have to check for existence of key in the dictionnary, then I'd use a full function rather than an inline one only because of clearity.

Comment: Are you suggesting to check for existence of key in every dictionary of the list?  Is it optimal in large list  of dicts?

Answer (score 1):

as I said in my comment, I wouldn't use a one-liner if you have to check for existence of a key in the dictionnary.

I beleive that the fastest way is to use the try/except:

```
def my_func(some_dict):
    out_dict = {}
    try:
        id = some_dict['key1']
    except KeyError:
        id = None
    try:
        long = some_dict["key4"]["coordinates"][0]
    except KeyError:
        long = None
    try:
        lat = some_dict["key4"]["coordinates"][1]
    except KeyError:
        lat = None
    try:
        act = some_dict["keyx"]
    except KeyError:
        act = None
    return {"id": id, "longitude": long, "latitude": lat,"active_status" : act}

data ={"data" : map(my_func,all_devices)}
```

If you still want a 'one-liner', then you could do something like:

```
data ={
        "data" : map(
            lambda m: {
                "id": m["key1"] if "key1" in m else None,
                "longitude": m["key4"]["coordinates"][0]  if "key4" in m else None,
                "latitude": m["key4"]["coordinates"][1]  if "key4" in m else None,
                "active_status" : m["keyx"]  if "keyx" in m else None
            },
            all_devices
        )
    }
```

or

```
data ={
        "data" : map(
            lambda m: {
                "id": ((if "key1" in m) and m["key1"]) or None,
                "longitude": ((if "key4" in m) and m["key4"]["coordinates"][0]) or None,
                "latitude":((if "key4" in m) and  m["key4"]["coordinates"][1]) or None,
                "active_status" : ((if "keyx" in m) and m["keyx"]) or None
            },
            all_devices
        )
    }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to check for existence of key in every dictionary of the list? Is it optimal in large list of dicts?

Comment: I'm suggesting to use the `try/except` clause. That would try to use the value if the key exists (without trying to check for its existence). The optimal would to not have to call a function at all, but I'm not sure if a loop would be better. Maybe using an iterator? What's your restriction for searching the most efficient way instead of the most understandable one?

Comment: From a standpoint of *style*, list comprehensions are preferred over using `map` and `lambda` because they are more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep your mapping simple, you have to make sure that the data is complete *before* applying the map.

If you can control what goes into the database, make sure you add the required fields there.

Otherwise, add the missing keys to the dictionaries after you have extracted them from the database but before running the `map`:

```
def checker(d):
    for k in ["key1", "key4", "keyx"]:
        if k not in d:
            d[k] = None  # or 0, or ''. Whatever works for you.

data = [checker(d) for d in data]
```